# What is a good way to move extruded letters in a mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, extrude

I need to move the letters 2021 in my model a little bit further to the right
[image] , but I dont know the best way to do this since they are already extruded.

How should I go about this ? Any answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is one of those times the value of non-destructive workflows is made apparent.  A learning experience we have all been through.

Comment: Flatten the year in Sculpt mode and extrude again ... @AllenSimpson +1 :)

Comment: As @vklidu said, nothing can be done except flattening it and making it again. We all have been there. I recommend using a Boolean modifier next time as you can easily move it if need be. Try bool tool add-on, it makes things even easier